# preg_match issues with '[' in quadodo login system

Tags: php

I'm absolutely confused with this:

```
$email = (isset($_POST['email']) && preg_match('@^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$@', $_POST['email']) && strlen($_POST['email']) <= 255 && strlen($_POST['email']) > 6) ? $_POST['email'] : false;
```

Error:

```
Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '[' in C:\xampp\htdocs\sales\qls-3.1.9\install\Install.class.php on line 283
```

and I've looked at the actual functions webpage from the [official php site](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

If anyone can help that would be epic!

Comment: if you have php >= 5.2 please use `filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that you're using `@` as regex delimiter and using `@` in the regex without escaping it.

Your regex:

```
#^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$#
```

Comment: +1 for explaining what the problem was, even though someone else downvoted you.

Comment: Thanks man I was absolutely stumped, now I feel like a moron though XD

Answer (score -1):

ok try this:

```
$email = (isset($_POST['email']) && preg_match('/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i', $_POST['email']) && strlen($_POST['email']) <= 255 && strlen($_POST['email']) > 6) ? $_POST['email'] : false;
```